# Interdependent Transactions with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, express, pg-promise

I am trying to build an app involves **posts** and **tags** for posts. For these I have a `post`, `tags` and `post_tag` table. `tags` has the tags I have defined before hand and in somewhere in the app is suggested to the user on the front-end. `post_tag` table holds the **post** and **tag** **ids** as pairs on each row.

I use express.js and postgreql and pg-promise.

As far as I know I need a transactional query(ies) for a create post operation.

Also I need a mechanism to detect if a **tag** was not in `tags` table when the user created the post, so that I can insert it on the fly, and I have a `tag_id` for each **tag** that is neccessary to use in `insertion` of the `post_id` and `tag_id` into `post_tag` table. Otherwise, I will have a `foreign key error` since I need to `post_tag` table's columns `post_id` and `tag_id` to reference `posts` and `tags` table `id` columns, respectively.

Here is the url function I use for this I have used so far unsuccessful:

```
privateAPIRoutes.post('/ask', function (req, res) {
    console.log('/ask req.body: ', req.body);
    // write to posts
    var post_id = ''
    var post_url = ''
    db.query(
        `
            INSERT INTO
                posts (title, text, post_url, author_id, post_type)
            VALUES
                ($(title), $(text), $(post_url), $(author_id), $(post_type))
            RETURNING id
        `,
        {
            title: req.body.title,
            text: req.body.text,
            post_url: slug(req.body.title),
            author_id: req.user.id,
            post_type: 'question'
        } // remember req.user contains decoded jwt saved by mw above.
    )
        .then(post => {
            console.log('/ask post: ', post);
            post_id = post.id
            post_url = post.post_url


            // if tag deos not exist create it here
            var tags = req.body.tags;
            console.log('2nd block tags1', tags);
            for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                if (tags[i].id == undefined) {
                    console.log('req.body.tags[i].id == undefined', tags[i].id);                        
                    var q1 = db.query("insert into tags (tag) values ($(tag)) returning id", {tag: tags[i].label})
                                .then(data => {
                                    console.log('2nd block tags2', tags);
                                    tags[i].id = data[0].id 


                                    // write to the post_tag
                                    db.tx(t => {
                                        var queries = [];
                                        for (var j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {

                                            var query = t.query(
                                                `
                                                    INSERT INTO
                                                        post_tag (post_id, tag_id)
                                                    VALUES
                                                        ($(post_id), $(tag_id))
                                                `,
                                                {
                                                    post_id: post_id,
                                                    tag_id: tags[j].id
                                                }
                                            )
                                            queries.push(query);
                                        }   
                                        return t.batch(queries)
                                    })
                                        .then(data => {
                                            res.json({post_id: post_id, post_url: post_url})
                                        })
                                        .catch(error => {
                                            console.error(error);
                                        })
                                })
                                .catch(error => {
                                    console.error(error);
                                });
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
});
```

Comment: If there is another approach it is welcome.

Comment: After you edited the code, you are creating a list of tags, and then for each tag you are creating a list of post_tags relevant to each tag? This isn't how you described the dependency. Therefore, I'm confused. I think you need to narrow your question ;)

Comment: The I need to assign an id for each tag inside the req.body.tags so I can insert them into post_tag table along with the post_id. If any of the user sent tags does not have id, that is the case when the tag was not in the tags table beforehand, I need to create them on the fly. But code may seem different, that is why it is erratic, I could not write my intention in the code. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem you have - you can't use the root-level `db` object inside a task or transaction. Trying to create a new connection while inside a transaction breaks the transaction logic. You would need to use `t.tx` in such cases. However, in your case I don't see that you need it at all.

**corrected code:**

```
privateAPIRoutes.post('/ask', (req, res) => {
    console.log('/ask req.body: ', req.body);
    db.tx(t => {
        return t.one(
            `
        INSERT INTO
        posts (title, text, post_url, author_id, post_type)
        VALUES
        ($(title), $(text), $(post_url), $(author_id), $(post_type))
        RETURNING *
        `,
            {
                title: req.body.title,
                text: req.body.text,
                post_url: slug(req.body.title),
                author_id: req.user.id,
                post_type: 'question'
            } // remember req.user contains decoded jwt saved by mw above.
        )
            .then(post => {
                console.log('/ask second query: post[0]: ', post);
                console.log('/ask second query: tags: ', req.body.tags);
                console.log('/ask second query: tags[0]: ', req.body.tags[0]);

                // the key piece to the answer:
                var tagIds = req.body.tags.map(tag => {
                    return tag.id || t.one("insert into tags(tag) values($1) returning id", tag.label, a=>a.id);
                });

                return t.batch(tagIds)
                    .then(ids => {
                        var queries = ids.map(id => {
                            return t.one(
                                `
                                INSERT INTO post_tag (post_id, tag_id)
                                VALUES ($(post_id), $(tag_id))
                                RETURNING post_id, tag_id
                                `,
                                {
                                    post_id: post.id,
                                    tag_id: id
                                }
                            )
                        });
                        return t.batch(queries);
                    });
            });
    })
        .then(data => {
            // data = result from the last query;
            console.log('/api/ask', data);
            res.json(data);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            // error
        });
});
```

The key here is simply to iterate through the tag id-s, and for the ones that are not set - use an insert. Then you settle them all by passing the array into `t.batch`.

---

Other recommendations:

- You should use method `one` when executing an insert that returns the new record columns.
- You should use `try`/`catch` only once there, on the transaction. This is relevant to how to use promises, and not just for this library
- You can place your queries into external SQL files, see [Query Files](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files)

---

To understand conditional inserts better, see [SELECT->INSERT](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/select-insert.md)

Comment: Hi @vitaly-t, I know you are the author of the pg-promise. I was just having substantial changes in the textual noncode part of the question for your info. Since I need a condidtional operation taht look if the user sent tag doe s exist on the tags table before hand, if not create on the fly and use its id in the insertion into pot_tag.

Comment: That part isn't clear from the code that you provided... You should have at least shown an attempt of inserting a conditional record there, so I would have something to correct... There is even no `IF` condition there....

Comment: I was on it while I mean correcting actually, code part has expanded as well. I have just edit it with conditional. Do you have any recommendation/correction for this too?

Comment: There is a bit of strange logic there now, as I described above. You should simplify your question.

Comment: @Işık I have updated the code according to what you described. I hope I got your logic right ;)

Comment: Wow I have just seen notification know, I was battling with the code.

Comment: @Işık The solution was trivial there, as it normally is with promises. It just takes the right mindset to understand promises and the fact that `pg-promise` follows the promise pattern precisely.

Comment: this worked very good. another thing if you don't mind. What if I need a query result or apart of it from the beginning of the transaction in the later parts of the transaction in another query? how to carry data down to deeper queries? Say if I need the `id`from the `posts` in the latest query above.

Comment: @Işık that's purely a promise question, not really for pg-promise library. You do this as you normally would with promises. And you should take your time learning promises ;)